# Creating and accessing a schema beginning with a numeric value in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I generate a 10-character alphanumeric random string as a schema name for each new tenant in my DB.

In this one instance, it generated "5ku2mug7m8" as the string. The schema was created correctly (in pic) but when accessing the schema, an error of

```
"ERROR:  syntax error at or near "5"
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM 5ku2mug7m8.tablename"
```

which I gather is due to the leading numeric. I tried wrapping the schema in double-quotes ("") but postgres doesn't accept that.

My question is: **if I cannot access a schema with a leading numeric, why does postgres allow the creation of it in the first place?** Now I have sitting in the DB a schema that can't be accessed -- unless it can be and I'm just missing it?

**EDIT:** From documentation,

> SQL identifiers and key words must begin with a letter (a-z, but also
>   letters with diacritical marks and non-Latin letters) or an underscore
>   (_). Subsequent characters in an identifier or key word can be
>   letters, underscores, digits (0-9), or dollar signs ($). Note that
>   dollar signs are not allowed in identifiers according to the letter of
>   the SQL standard, so their use might render applications less
>   portable...

But why allow creation of the schema without any errors in the first place? Curious.

[image: schema name]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably created the schema with pgAdmin, and that tool automatically added the double quotes for you.

You can certainly delete the schema with

```
DROP SCHEMA "5ku2mug7m8";
```

unless you have nasty things like leading or trailing blanks in the schema name.

You can find out the real schema name with:

```
SELECT quote_ident(nspname)
FROM pg_namespace
WHERE nspname LIKE '%5%';
```

Your experience and your research of the documentation is valuable. You have seen why it is a bad idea to pick object or column names (“identifiers”) that are valid SQL identifiers and don't need double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a schema whose name starts with a digit if the schema name is using double quotes.

Demo with psql:

```
# select version();
                                                 version                        

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------
 PostgreSQL 12.3 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (R
ed Hat 4.8.5-39), 64-bit

# create schema "5ku";
CREATE SCHEMA

# create table "5ku".t(x int);
CREATE TABLE

# select * from "5ku".t;
 x 
---
(0 rows)
```